# How to find the max value in a hash table that is manually implemented?

Tags: python, max, hashtable

Hi I'm new to Python and I implemented a hash table that counts the number of occurences of a letter in a word.

For example the hash table currently stores this:

```
{l:1, r:1, t:1, u:1, a:1, c:1, d:2, e:1, }
```

I want to find the max value in the hash table, which is 2. I implemented an iterator so I can iterate through the hash table.  I managed to find the max value like this:

EDIT: I implemented a hashtable class with the set item, get item functions.

```
class HashTableQuadratic:

def __init__(self, size=10):
    self.count = 0
    self.table_size = size
    self.array = build_array(self.table_size)
    self.collision=0
    self.totalProbeLength=0

 //some code here


tempList=[]
for item in hashTable:
if item!=None:
    tempList.append(item[1])
maxNum=max(tempList)
print(maxNum)
```

But is there a better way to do it without using a tempList and max built in function?

Comment: You mean you re-implemented python's [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)?

Comment: Showing us the `__init__` method of your class doesn't really tell us anything useful. Showing us the interface of the class might be useful, on the other hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `hashTable` object appears to be an iterable of key-value pairs.

First, not that your four lines of code:

```
tempList=[]
for item in hashTable:
if item!=None:
    tempList.append(item[1])
```

… is equivalent to a one-liner comprehension:

```
tempList = [item[1] for item in hashTable if item is not None]
```

And it's trivial to turn this into a lazy iterator, instead of building a list in memory:

```
it = (item[1] for item in hashTable if item is not None)
```

And you can inline this directly in the `max` call:

```
maxNum = max(item[1] for item in hashTable if item is not None)
```

---

As a side note, notice that I used `item is not None` instead of `item != None`. You almost *never* want to compare to `None` with `==` or `!=`. The rule of thumb is:

- If you want any truthy value, use `if item`.
- If you want any non-`None` value, use `if item is not None`.
- If you want any non-`None` value, while specifically allowing other classes to override `__eq__` and compare as equal to `None`, use `if item != None`.

---

However, it's worth noting that if you want to build a custom hash table, you probably want it to act like a dict—or at least like a [`Mapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Mapping). Implementing the `Mapping` interface is very easy, and it means your object can duck-type as a dict.

And, if you do that, you can use the same code you'd use with a dict:

```
maxNum = max(hashTable.values())
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your class is the same as [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter),  you can simply use `max` this way:

```
max(hashTable.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])
```

This will return `('d', 2)` with your example. You may simplify it if you're not interested in knowing which key has the max value.

We pass all items as `(key, value)` pairs, and use the `key` argument of [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) to tell it to compare items by value.

Comment: First, I think the OP's custom class isn't the same as `Counter`, or even like a dict, or his existing code wouldn't work. It seems to act like an iterable of key-value pairs rather than an iterable of keys, so I assume there's no `items()` method. But, then again, you don't _need_ the `items()` method; you can just use `hashTable` itself.

Comment: Second, he seems to only want the count, not the pair. Which you could do `max(hashTable, key=lambda item: item(1))[1]`, but I think it's more readable to just do `max(item[1] for item in hashTable)`.

Comment: @abarnert the interface is somewhat different, but in essence the functionality is exactly that of `Counter`. Even the stated purpose, at the beginning of his question is *“count the number of occurrences of a letter in a word”*, and the sample output is exactly what you would get out of `Counter('cddelrtua')`. I would put the different interface just on the account of not being used to conforming to standard python idioms, not intended design.

Comment: Agreed on the count though. I read that one so much, and it ends in *"great I have the count, how do I know which key it was?"* so often I just jump to that. Which is incorrect when the count really was it.